# Merge two xml documents into one replacing original root elements with new root

Tags: php, xml

I have two data sources in XML which I want to merge in one XML document with a PHP script.

First source XML document

```
<book>
 <id>1</id>
 <title>Republic</title>
</book>
```

Second source XML document

```
<data>
 <author>Plato</author>
 <language>Greek</language>
</data>
```

I want to combine the two to get

```
<book>
 <id>1</id>
 <title>Republic</title>
 <author>Plato</author>
 <language>Greek</language>
</book>
```

But what I get is

```
<book>
 <id>1</id>
 <title>Republic</title>
<data>
 <author>Plato</author>
 <language>Greek</language>
</data></book>
```

This is my code

```
$first = new DOMDocument("1.0", 'UTF-8');
$first->formatOutput = true;
$first->loadXML(firstXML);

$second = new DOMDocument("1.0", 'UTF-8');
$second->formatOutput = true;
$second->loadXML(secondXML);

$second = $second->documentElement;

$first->documentElement->appendChild($first->importNode($second, TRUE));

$first->saveXML();

$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", 'UTF-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->appendChild($xml->importNode($first->documentElement,true));

return $xml->saveXML();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need . You have to add the nodes using loop

```
        $first = new DOMDocument("1.0", 'UTF-8');
        $first->formatOutput = true;
        $first->loadXML($xml_string1);



        $second = new DOMDocument("1.0", 'UTF-8');
        $second->formatOutput = true;
        $second->loadXML($xml_string2);
        $second = $second->documentElement;

        foreach($second->childNodes as $node)
        {

           $importNode = $first->importNode($node,TRUE);
           $first->documentElement->appendChild($importNode);
        }


        $first->saveXML();

        $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", 'UTF-8');
        $xml->formatOutput = true;
        $xml->appendChild($xml->importNode($first->documentElement,true));

        return $xml->saveXML();
```

Comment: Thanks. It works as a charm. Just why does it leave an empty line just before the <author> tag?

Comment: @ Nice to help you mate ..for your question :
XML_TEXT_NODEs have no children and are always named '#text'. Depending on how whitespace is handled, your tree may have "empty" #text nodes as children of <body> and elsewhere. REF http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php  . I think we should not bother about it ..

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `$second` var, which is initially the DOMDocument, is set to `$second->documentElement` which is the root node.

In your case, the root node is the `<data>` node.

So, when you `appendChild` `$second`, with the deep parameter set to `TRUE`, it will apend the `<data>` node and all its children.

Solution: You should instead, append all children of this `$second`.

```
foreach($second->childNodes as $secondNode){
    $first->documentElement->appendChild($secondNode);
}
```